# Converting a string into a command using Pymel

Tags: arrays, string, list, command, pymel

I currently have a list of strings in which I need to convert into a command.

```
IE: 
"checkerText.outAlpha" needs to be checkerText.outAlpha
```

Is there a command that will convert a string into a command for pymel?

I need this so I can connect two shaders together.

```
IE: 
'checkerText.outAlpha' >> 'layText.inputs[0].alpha'

                   needs to be 

checkerText.outAlpha >> layText.inputs[0].alpha
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically with the layeredTexture Node the `inputs` attribute is actually a pymel method so it returns the input nodes of said node. In order to achieve the desired result you have to declare "layeredTexture1.inputs[1].alpha" as an attribute explicitly via pymel's `Attribute()` class or pass it through a pretty handy command pymel has to offer called `PyNode()`, which does kind of what you wanted. [This](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/PyMel/pynodes.html) should give you everything you should need to know about PyNodes. Some examples of all this would be:

```
PyNode("checker1").outAlpha >> PyNode("layeredTexture1.inputs[1].alpha") # The whole attr needs to be in the string because of the above explenation.

Attribute("checker1.outAlpha") >> Attribute("layeredTexture1.inputs[1].alpha")
```

Using PyNode is prefered but you can play around with both.